# Link an ODBC database table into Postgres

Tags: postgresql

I have an Attache 7 GL system, which runs its own proprietary ODBC connector to its database. I want to connect to these tables in Postgres via odbc and get all the data into the Postgres database.

How can I connect to an ODBC database direct from Postgres and move the tables over into Postgres?

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PostgreSQL itself doesn't let you connect out to a ODBC datasource. What you can do is use a script (in any language that can speak ODBC) or some tool such as Microsoft DTS (if you have SQL Server somewhere) to transfer the data over using ODBC. But it'll be a one-way copy, it won't give you live views of the data.

Answer (score 0):

There is a possibility with ODBC-Link:
http://www.postgresql.org/message-id/4BB5BD4C.1050508@cybertec.at